How to extract the tensor from a <dtype = resource> handle in tensorflow?
I'm currently printing some variables in the tesnorflow backend for debugging purposes and wish to print their size in bytes. However, their dtype turns out to be <dtype= resource> and I haven't been able to find any APIs online to extract the associated tensor attributes. How can I go about this?
